# mysql update and set sum value of last 8 hours of the current row

Tags: mysql, sum, sql-update, calculated-columns

Hi I would like to count the sum of chat_duration from 8 hours ago of the current data  
 
I have : 
`agent` text  
`start_time` datetime  
`end_time` datetime  
`chat_duration` bigint

and i need to insert the calculation result into `past8_hours_chat_duration`  
so when i have :

```
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------+---------------------------+
| id | agent  | start_time | end_time | chat_duration | past8_hours_chat_duration |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------+---------------------------+
|  1 | agent1 |   00.00.00 | 00.01.00 |            60 |                           |
|  2 | agent2 |   00.00.00 | 00.01.00 |            60 |                           |
|  3 | agent1 |   00.02.00 | 00.04.00 |           120 |                           |
|  4 | agent1 |   08.02.00 | 08.03.00 |            60 |                           |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------+---------------------------+
```

I'll try to explain as much as possible.

For each row I need to find the sum of duration past 8 hours of the current agent 
or in another word : where the `start_time` is after (`currentData.start_time` minus `8 hour`) and not itself ( current row) and not where the `start_time` is after `currentData.start_time`

for id 1, there is no session  for `agent1` where the `start_time` is after `00.00.00` minus 8 hour ( current start_time) so the total is 0

for id 2, there is also no session  for `agent2` where the `start_time` is after `00.00.00` minus 8 hour ( current start_time) so the total is 0

for id 3, since the start_time of id 1 is > 00.02.00(current) - 8 hours so the total is 60

and 
for id 4, since the start_time of
 id 1 is < 08.02.00(current) - 8 hours 
& id 3 is > 08.02.00(current) - 8 hours 
so the total is 120(from id 3)

i'm using mysql
at first i'm using :

```
UPDATE chats AS c
JOIN ( SELECT   agent, 
 SUM(chat_duration) AS sum_duration
 FROM     abc 
 GROUP BY agent
 ) AS c2
 ON c2.agent = c.agent 
SET c.past8_hours_chat_duration = c2.sum_duration
WHERE c.id < 10;
```

but that's  sum of all the agent duration, how should i find the sum of the past 8 hours chat data.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a query using a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*,
       (select sum(c2.duration)
        from chats c2
        where c2.agent = c.agent and
              c2.start_time > c.start_time - interval 8 hour and
              c2.start_time <= c.start_time
       ) as past8_hours_chat_duration
from chats c;
```

In MySQL, integrating this into an `update` is tricky, because you can only refer to the table being updated in the `join` clause.  So:

```
update chats c join
       (select c.*,
               (select sum(c2.duration)
                from chats c2
                where c2.agent = c.agent and
                      c2.start_time > c.start_time - interval 8 hour and
                      c2.start_time <= c.start_time
               ) as past8_hours_chat_duration
        from chats c
       ) cc
       on c.id = cc.id
    c.past8_hours_chat_duration = coalesce(cc.past8_hours_chat_duration, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, That do the trick.
I think i need to refrain myself to update using mySQL, since on large data it takes a long time. :D